# Does Bran know that Arya is a faceless man?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I know that Bran from *Game of Thrones* has the ability to see everything.

The Night King has his mark on Bran and he can see Bran's visions.

If Bran didn't know that Arya is a face shifter then the Night King doesn't know about Arya, which may have led to his death in S08E03.

In books or TV, was there any evidence that Bran has seen Arya in his vision or do we have to wait for the book?

Comment: Why wouldn't he know? Also, as Arya didn't use any particular powers of the faceless during the episode, I'm personally not sure how knowledge or ignorance of her training in that area would be relevant to the outcome.

Comment: Are we sure "he can see Bran's visions" ? I thought he just knew where Bran was, but I haven't checked back to confirm that.

Comment: Yes, I believe Bran planned it all, to the very last detail, for long time. It's hinted by what he said to Theon, I'll read about it and come back with answer if I'll find solid stuff to back it up. (Including something that back up my theory that the Night King **can't** see/share Bran's visions at will)

Comment: He did hand that dagger over to Arya under that same tree.

Comment: @ToddWilcox. I'm not sure if she did or not. Jaqen (1st face) somehow was either able to read Arya's mind or he just received sensory information from the beyond, as he recited the names off of her list. This ability doesn't seem full blown, but something that occasionally happens via [glamour] magic & isn't exclusive to TFM, as once again Mel recited a line of a dead person & somehow Arya "received" information of what she is "suppose" to do. Last season Arya seemed to this to Sansa to. Then there is however she snuk up on "so and so". It may be that everyone "serves" the same thing

Comment: I think whether or he knows or understands what Arya is or what abilities she has is moot, as long as he had seen how these events happen.

Comment: he knows what he wants to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It's more he has access to all the knowledge in the world.

Although this hasn't been confirmed, it's very likely that Bran doesn't actually "know everything" in the sense that we all think about it, but rather he has access to anything he knows to look for, here's a nice Quora post explaining this but with him not knowing about Cersei's plan instead of Arya's powers.

> So for Bran to “see” things (not counting his warging into
>   crows/ravens/animals), he has to know to look for it.
>
> So, 3 Eyes (before Bran) wanted to show Bran the Tower of Joy fight
>   scene and the death of Lyanna. So Bran searched in his Game of Thrones
>   YouTube folder (well technically 3 eyes’ youtube folder) and they
>   watched it. That's why Bran really only thought to say “Hey Jon isn’t
>   Snow, He’s Sand!”. Now if 3 Eye (had planned to before dying) show
>   that Rhegar and Lyanna were actually in a legitimate two sided
>   relationship filled with love and nookie, then Bran would know about
>   Jon being a Targ.
>
> However, Bran didn’t know that and technically didn’t have a reason to
>   even ask since in his mind, and really anyone’s mind that is not privy
>   to the R + L = J theory (they wouldn’t be in story), he probably
>   thinks the key points are Jon is actually a Sand, and Lyanna dyed in
>   child birth. Maybe he Brangoogles who Lyanna had nookie with to make
>   baby Jon, but the wedding in the forrest might not be something he’d
>   actively be looking for.
>
> So unless Bran has a reason to tune into Cersei being a shithead with
>   Euron channel, he won’t. I’m sure someone could ask Bran to, but it
>   doesn’t seem like the characters know the full extent of his powers
>   besides maybe Meera but she’s gone home now.
>
> So like many others, I think Bran can see what he wants, he search to
>   see what he wants, but like me, unless he wants to see a certain scene
>   or whatever, its not just all playing in his head.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[If Bran Stark can see everything, why didn't he see Cersei's plan with the Golden Company and the mercenaries? - Quora](https://www.quora.com/If-Bran-Stark-can-see-everything-why-didnt-he-see-Cerseis-plan-with-the-Golden-Company-and-the-mercenaries)</sub>

Although this hasn't been confirmed it does seem likely, and if we assume it is true then he probably wouldn't have known to look for Arya's training with the faceless men.